# Is it possible to install Maverick into an existing LUKS partition?

Tags: 10.10, installation, encryption

I'm about to do a re-install of Maverick on a laptop with an existing installation that's in an encrypted (LUKS) partition. (I'm re-installing because it's currently an xfs filesystem in there, and I'm trying to determine if xfs is the reason disk performance is so incredibly bad.)

The normal desktop installer of course doesn't know what that partition is, and the "advanced" tool doesn't appear to provide me any way of telling it.  I'm downloading the "alternate" iso now, but I'm curious (for the next time I go through this) to know whether there is some trick to doing that with just the plain "desktop" iso.

Answer (score 2):

The alternate installer CD supports LUKS.

On the regular live-CD, it might work after installing the necessary tools and mounting the partition manually (but I didn't test that).

Comment: Yes, OK.  But even with the alternate disk I could see no way to make it find the LVM stuff - in other words, the partition is encrypted at the point the partitioning tool is looking at it. It doesn't really matter of course, because since I'm doing a complete reinstall I can just re-build the volume group.  Thanks!

Comment: You didn't mention LVM in your question...
?